# narrowing types using the in operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

What is the proper way to narrow down an object after checking that a property actually exists in TypeScript?

I realized that you can't just use the `property in obj` operator and have TypeScript realize that obj is a `{property: any }` object.

I have the following example:

```js
let o1 = {}

if ('name' in o1 && (o1 as {name: string }).name === 'string') {
    // type of o1 is {}
    console.log(o1)

    const o2 = o1 as {name: string}
    // now type of o2 is {name: string}
    console.log(o2)
}

const hasName = (o: Object): o is { name: string } => 'name' in o && typeof (o as {name: string}).name === 'string'

if (hasName(o1)) {
    // type of o1 is { name: string }
    console.log(o1)
}
```

available also in [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gjBC8EDeBfAsAKEwSwGYQAoByAOwEMBbEIibE6OAMkcNgjIGdlyqAuCDmABOdAOYQUASgB0PEAniIigkSVFFJyTBB0QA9HohgAngAd5UfG2xdU23QGMoJDlFDTgUUQViTM9nScXSCgAJgQGdls5fhUxdAxdfUMSKAB3IzMLK3CbbkoQWOF4gIgg13dPbzC-DATMcsgAC04AOQKIn34AeQAjACsQBzBJfihaWwgYgWK1CQQAPghSApo6aAhmTPNLVij8vhnVUSlZDsUlOLUifww8QhaOdqofGElNJFKDbezIvKQpgUiscJKVym4QB4vK9aiggA)

Is there a better way to do it or the only options are to define a type predicate or explicitelly cast it? I'm both cases it's me telling typescript what o1 type is.

And in that case, why can't TypeScript just infer it from the `property in obj` statement?

Comment: try [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoGLMW)

Comment: This is a really nice piece os code, any idea why something like this is not part of TypeScript itself?

Answer (score 1):

One way around this would be to declare `o1` as having an optional `name` property:

```
let o1: { name?: string }
```

You could then drop the typecasts.

In addition, [TypeScript 4.9 has strengthened `in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator) so that you can get away without this -- even if the type of `o1` is `unknown`.

Note: Your line 3 is missing a `typeof` before `(o1 as {name: string }).name === 'string'`.